# Dividing one row by the one beneath (in stacks of 2)

Tags: r

I want to create a new table with an inequality measure (ratio top/bottom 20% share of income) and thus have to divide the two rows for each country.

[image: Table]

I tried (with a new table with only the first country for clarity):

```
data_inequality = read.csv("d4d6da20-5e57-421d-80b2-adca48912139_Data.csv")

Group1 <- data_inequality[1:2, ]

x <- Group1[1,-1]/Group1[2,-1]
```

But that yields the following error:

> 1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 3: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 4: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 5: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 6: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 7: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 8: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors

It does not seem to be that hard but somehow I am stuck.

Thanks for any ideas!

Ani

Comment: Your data are not numbers. If you fetch some of your columns you will likely see that they have ".." around the numbers. Some of the rows contain text when they shouldn't, or you have decmial point issues I guess. Regardless, we need to see some of the file to be able to help.

Comment: also, you want to add `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` in you read-statement.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help more if you provided a minimal reproducible exemple, but I have a few guesses that might help.

As mentioned by @Sirius and @William, you are reading numeric values as factors, which can lead to many serious mistakes when converting to numeric later.

My guess is that you could call `read.csv("d4d6da20-5e57-421d-80b2-adca48912139_Data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "-")` to get numbers as numbers.

Then, one way to do the calculations you need would be to tidy your data. The way I would do it (and I know other people would do it differently) would be:

```
# Load the tidyverse packages
library(tidyverse)

# Instead of having one variable per year, have the variable "year" and the variable "income"
data_inequality %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = X2005..YR2005.:X2009..YR2009., names_to = "year", values_to = "income") %>% 
  select(Country.Code, Series.Code, year, income) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Series.Code, values_from = income) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = SI.DST.05TH.20/SI.DST.FRST.20)
```

Note that you have to adjust the code if you have more years to the right of what you are showing in the image. Also, I used the `select()` function to remove some of the variables, since they could break the pivoted data.frame.